# How to prevent this KeyboardInterrupt error from showing up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, error-handling, keyboardinterrupt

I am writing a program in python, and part of the program reads lines from a file and prints them. However, while it is printing, if I press a random key I get a KeyboardInterrupt error. This is because I have a try and except case, however, some output shows up that I do not want to show up. This is my code that executes inside the main function:

```
for line in output.stdout:
    line = str(line)
    print(line)
```

This is my code that contains the try and except.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    if os.path.exists('drop.json') == True:
        drops()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.stderr.close()
except (BrokenPipeError, IOError):
    if os.path.exists('drop.txt') == True:
        file = open("drop.txt","a+")
        file.write('BrokenPipeError | IOError Exception occurred')
        file.close()
except Exception as e:
    if os.path.exists('drop.txt') == True:
        file = open("drops.txt","a+")
        file.write(' interrupted: {}'.format(str(e)))
        file.close()
```

While the file is being printed, if I press a random key, it stops the program and outputs this error message which I do not want. The preferred behavior is for the printing to end, the program to stop, and there to be no further output at all. This is the error message that shows up when I press a random key:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "drop.py", line 100, in <module> drops()
File "drop.py", line 321, in drops print(line)   
BrokenPipeError: [Err 56] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "drop.py", line 756, in <module>file = open ("drop.txt","a+")
File "boot.py", line 68, in decoding
def decoding(do_setlocale=True):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Instead of all these error messages showing up, if I press a random key during the printing of lines, I would the printing to end, the program to stop, and no error messages to be displayed. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out here. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: From the trace you provide, The `KeyboardInterrupt` you want to get rid of is occurring during the execution of the code in the except block for the `BrokenPipe` error, therefore your existing except clause for `KeyboardInterrupt` will not catch it.

Comment: @gallen, thank you for this input. Do you know how I could possibly edit the code to get the behavior I would like? I have been trying but cannot seem to succeed. I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Wrap it in another try except. But that starts to look ugly, so I'd break the code from your bottom two excepts into a function that excepts the line you'll write to that file as an argument. Inside that function would be where you'd have this extra try/except block to handle the deeper `KeyboardInterrupt`. I can't say if that's the _right way_, but it is *a* way.

Comment: A “random key”?

Comment: @DavisHerring yes, on my keyboard

Comment: @Sanil: It’s not normal for just any old key to result in an exception of any kind (although `SIGIO` comes to mind).  What exactly are you doing with your keyboard?

Comment: @DavisHerring thanks for your response. Basically, I want this program to terminate with any key. Any key on the keyboard should basically act as "control c" to seamlessly end the printing :) I hope this adds some clarity.

Comment: @Sanil: I think it does add clarity, but that means you should edit your question to distinguish what *does* happen (perhaps undesirably) and under what circumstances from what you *want* to happen (under a possibly different set of circumstances).